# trying to run COBOL .exe using C++ program

Tags: cobol

I'm still learning how to program but I have a simple question. I have the following code for running an executable COBOL program through C++, but I am getting COBOL errors: 251 and 410

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    system("C:\\rmcobol\\runcobol.exe SOLOCAJA.COB c=windows.cfg L=WOWRT.DLL"); 
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");  
    return 0;
}
```

I assume there must be a very simple reason for this, but I am clueless so far. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you run the command that you are passing to `system` directly from the command line, does it work?

Comment: What happens when you run that command line from a Command Prompt?

Comment: ight help http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1119251&page=5

Comment: @AGE that question still has no answer...
If I see it correctly you weren't able to execute this on plain cmd either, correct? In this case it would be reasonable to remove the "C" part completely... Also: how do you get _two_ errors when executing a single command?

Comment: @SimonSobisch I was able to figure out how to do this and it has been at least 10 years since then, so if I remember correctly I wrote a C++ file which handled calling the COBOL methond to print, I only needed to collect relevant data to support the existing COBOL method

Answer (score 2):

Error 410 is a "configuration file not found" error based on Apendix A of the [user guide](http://downloads.microfocus.com/liant/download/pdf/rmug_e01.pdf). Are you sure your `windows.cfg` file is in the directory you're running your code in?

Failing that, error 251 states "Incorrect runtime command" and all the samples I can find have an uppercase `C`. So maybe change your C program to use to:

```
system("C:\\rmcobol\\runcobol.exe SOLOCAJA.COB C=WINDOWS.CFG L=WOWRT.DLL");
```

and see if that fixes it (a long shot, I know, but I've seen stranger things than that).

---

Based on update:

> I tried changing the c to a C on the C=WINDOWS.CFG, ran it in C++ and directly on the Command Line, no change. I am still looking into the reasons behind this, and I read through tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1119251&page=5 but I couldn't use any of that info. Any extra tips would be gold at this point. THANKS!

A couple of questions:

- Has it *ever* worked in this environment?
- Is it failing on *both* cmdline and within C (just want to clarify)?
- Does windows.cfg actually exist in the current directory when you run it?
- Are you running it in a directory with spaces (like `My Documents`)?

Other than that, maybe post the windows.cfg file, though the error seems pretty explicit that it's config file not *found* rather than error in config file.

Comment: I tried changing the c to a C on the C=WINDOWS.CFG, ran it in C++ and directly on the Command Line, no change. I am still looking into the reasons behind this, and I read through tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1119251&page=5 but I couldn't use any of that info. Any extra tips would be gold at this point. THANKS!

Comment: 1. This is the first time I test it on this environment.
2. It is failing on both cmdline and within C.
3. Yes it does exist.
4. The directory has no spaces.

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Perhaps it is conflict with the RM/COBOL or the compiler? I am trying to keep it real simple using DevC++ and C++ code to run the program before I decide to implement it.

Comment: All I can suggest at this point is to (if it's been running elsewhere) try and figure out the difference between the running and non-running environment. Beyond that, all I can do is suggest you contact the vendor: http://supportline.microfocus.com/xmlloader.asp?type=home# ... sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help though! I will contact the vendor, if I find a solution I will post it